# sharepoint web part asking login credentials

Tags: authentication, redirect, sharepoint

I have a Sharepoint Web Part that when added to a page in a Belgium Sharepoint site is requiring login credentials. This same Web Part has previously been added to pages in other Sharepoint sites and works as it is intended without requiring login credentials. I have compared the web.config in the Belgium site to the others and I don't see any differences.

For instance, let's say I add a breadcrumb webpart in BelgiumTest.aspx page. Also I add the same webpart to italytest.aspx page. After adding the webpart when I try to access BelgiumTest.aspx , it is redirecting me to login.aspx page.

Does below entry in web config have any influence on such behavior?

```xml
<rule name=BE patternsyntax="exactmatch" stopprocessing="true">
    <match url="belgium"/>
    <action type="redirect" url="/sites/belgium/" redirecttype="found"/>
</rule>
```

Any ideas what could be causing the problem?

Comment: Which behavior is correct?  Can you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing how to reproduce the problem?  Stack overflow is a site for programming Q&A so, to help you, we need to see some **programmatic** way to reproduce the problem.  If this isn't a coding problem, maybe instead see [Sharepoint intranet keeps asking for credentials for some users](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/231409/91223) and related questions at [sharepoint.se].

Comment: Let's say I add a breadcrumb webpart in BelgiumTest.aspx page. Also I add the same webpart to italytest.aspx page.  After adding the webpart when I try to access BelgiumTest.aspx , it is redirecting me to login.aspx page

Comment: Does below entry in web config have any influence on such behavior? <rule name=BE patternsyntax="exactmatch" stopprocessing="true"> <match url="belgium"/> <action type="redirect" url="/sites/belgium/" redirecttype="found"/></rule>